# Cell Box Lines not showing correctly in Latex Table

Tags: tables

I have the following but in the cells where there are the results the cell box lines are not showing correctly as you can see in the screenshot. Any help to solve this? Thanks

**Table**

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|{1cm}|{2.5cm}|{2.5cm}|{2.5cm}|} 
\hline
Question & Yes & No & Maybe  \\ 
\hline
As a Coach, would you use this type \\ of system instead of the traditional 
method?        
&   11   &  2     &    2     \\ 
\hline 
Do you think that this system will \\ save you time to identify a player's 
position?         & 9     &  2    &  4  \\
\hline
Does the system has any errors/bugs \\ that interfered during the testing?     
&   3     &  12   &  0 \\
\hline
Do you think the system achieved the \\ necessary results for your work?    
& 10  &  4   &   1 \\
\hline
Is the System user-friendly to use?        &
14  &  0   &  1  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:3}
\end{table}
```

**Result**.

[image: Result Screenshot]

Comment: Could you please make your example compilable by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages? Apart from that, `{1cm}` is not the correct syntax to specify a table column. Maybe you wanted to use `p{1cm}` instead. If I use `p` type columns for all the coluns, I get a different output than you, as the first column is a lot narrower than the last three.

Comment: Also, there is no need for manual linebreaks if you use `p` (or `m`) type column, so simply correct the column specifications and remove the `\\ ` within the question text and your table should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains invalid column specifications. Instead of `{1cm}` you maybe intended to use `p{1cm}`. However, if I add the missing letters to  make the code compilable, I don't get the output you show in your question as the first column is very narrow. Changing the column specifier of the first column to `p{7cm}` or something else and the last three columns to `c` type columns gives us a result that is close to the screenshot.

The missing vertical lines are caused, because the second row of your table misses three `&`signs. If you add them, the vertical lines will be complete. However, if you use `p` type columns, there is no need for manual linebreaks. See first table in my MWE.

If you nevertheless insist on manual linebreaks inside of table cells, use `\newline` insead of `\\`. To horizontally center the text in the first column, use `>{\Centering}p{7cm}`. If you also want vertically centered, text, replace `p` by `m`. (See second table in my MWE).

Personally, I would suggest a different layout using the `tabularx` package for an `X` type column that automatically calculates the width of the respective column so that the whole table is as wide as a specified widht (textwidth inn my example). Also I'd avoid vertical lines and replace teh horizontal lines by rules from the `booktabs` package. (See third table in my MWE):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}    % Needed for the second example.
\usepackage{ragged2e} % Needed for the second example.

\usepackage{tabularx} % Needed for the third example.
\usepackage{booktabs} % Needed for the third example.

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|c|c|c|} 
\hline
Question & Yes & No & Maybe  \\ 
\hline
As a Coach, would you use this type  of system instead of the traditional 
method?        
&   11   &  2     &    2     \\ 
\hline 
Do you think that this system will  save you time to identify a player's 
position?         & 9     &  2    &  4  \\
\hline
Does the system has any errors/bugs  that interfered during the testing?     
&   3     &  12   &  0 \\
\hline
Do you think the system achieved the  necessary results for your work?    
& 10  &  4   &   1 \\
\hline
Is the System user-friendly to use?        &
14  &  0   &  1  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:3}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\Centering}m{7cm}|c|c|c|} 
\hline
Question & Yes & No & Maybe  \\ 
\hline
As a Coach, would you use this type \newline of system instead of the traditional 
method?        
&   11   &  2     &    2     \\ 
\hline 
Do you think that this system will \newline save you time to identify a player's 
position?         & 9     &  2    &  4  \\
\hline
Does the system has any errors/bugs  that interfered during the testing?     
&   3     &  12   &  0 \\
\hline
Do you think the system achieved the  necessary results for your work?    
& 10  &  4   &   1 \\
\hline
Is the System user-friendly to use?        &
14  &  0   &  1  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:3}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xccc} 
\toprule
Question & Yes & No & Maybe  \\ 
\midrule
As a Coach, would you use this type  of system instead of the traditional 
method?        
&   11   &  2     &    2     \\  
Do you think that this system will  save you time to identify a player's 
position?         & 9     &  2    &  4  \\
Does the system has any errors/bugs  that interfered during the testing?     
&   3     &  12   &  0 \\
Do you think the system achieved the  necessary results for your work?    
& 10  &  4   &   1 \\
Is the System user-friendly to use?        &
14  &  0   &  1  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{table:3}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the third example i would add `\addlinespace` between rows in table body. (+1)

Comment: Works Fine. Used Second Example. Thanks